# "Doesn't have a navController set" error why?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I wanna open TaskDetailFragment by clicking on titles of tasks. But android studio doesn't see my navController, moreover, it says that navController is unused variable.  Why? What to do? I have utterly need to fix it as soon as possible. I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#FFF">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/task_graph" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

task_graph.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/task_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/taskListFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/taskListFragment"
        android:name="com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster.TaskListFragment"
        android:label="TaskListFragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/taskDetailFragment"
        android:name="com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster.TaskDetailFragment"
        android:label="TaskDetailFragment">
        <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/deepLink"
            app:uri="app://taskmaster.taskDetailFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

TodoAdapter

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster

import android.graphics.Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.CheckBox
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.net.toUri
import androidx.navigation.NavDeepLinkRequest
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster.databinding.ItemTodoBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch


class TodoAdapter(
    private var todos: MutableList<Todo>, private val todoDao: TodoDao
):RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {
    class TodoViewHolder( ItemTodoBinding: ItemTodoBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemTodoBinding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {

        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val ItemTodoBinding = ItemTodoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)

        return TodoViewHolder(
            return TodoViewHolder(ItemTodoBinding)
        )
    }
    private fun toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle: TextView, isChecked:Boolean){
        if(isChecked){
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags or STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        }else{
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags and STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
          val curTodo = todos[position]
          holder.itemView.apply{
              val tvTodoTitle = findViewById(R.id.tvTodoTitle) as TextView
              tvTodoTitle.text = curTodo.title
              val cbDone = findViewById(R.id.cbDone) as CheckBox
              val deleteBtn = findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn) as Button
              cbDone.isChecked = curTodo.isChecked
              toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, curTodo.isChecked)
              cbDone.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                  toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, isChecked)
                  curTodo.isChecked = !curTodo.isChecked
              }
              cbDone.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener{
                  GlobalScope.launch {
                      todoDao.update(curTodo)
                      todoDao.delete(curTodo)
                  }
                      todos.removeAll { todo ->
                          todo.isChecked
                      }
                      notifyDataSetChanged()
              })

              deleteBtn.setOnClickListener{
                  GlobalScope.launch {
                      todoDao.delete(curTodo)
                  }
                  notifyDataSetChanged()
              }
              tvTodoTitle.setOnClickListener {
                  val request = NavDeepLinkRequest.Builder
                      .fromUri(TaskListFragment.TASK_DETAIL_URI.toUri())
                      .build()
                  findNavController().navigate(request)
              }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
          return todos.size
    }

}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster.databinding.ActivityMainBinding



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        val fragment = TaskListFragment()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit()
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you doing Fragment transactions at all? Just adding your NavHostFragment is enough. Have you tried removing all that transaction code in your activity?

Comment: I need task list fragment as my start screen

Comment: Yes, that's what your graph is doing already.

Comment: oh good. it helps thank you. Tell me plz if I wanna send information from one fragment to another using deeplink: ```  tvTodoTitle.setOnClickListener {
                  val request = NavDeepLinkRequest.Builder
                      .fromUri("${TASK_DETAIL_URI}?${TASK_BUNDLE_KEY}=${curTodo.title}&${TASK_DATE_BUNDLE_KEY}=${curTodo.date}".toUri())
                      .build()
                  findNavController().navigate(request)
              }```  I don't know what to use insted of curTodo. But I have the error required value is null. I don't have view model only data class